# Django form request method is always GET

Tags: html, django, post, django-forms, http-post

This is the html code:

```
    <form method='POST'>{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value='save'/>
</form>
```

This is the path in url.py:

```
path('student/create/', student_create_view, name='student-create')
```

This is my code in views.py:

```
def student_create_view(request):
form = StudentForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    form = StudentForm
context = {
    'form': form
}
return render(request, "personnel/student_create.html", context)
```

I also tried using action attribute and adding or removing "/" to the end of the path.

Comment: Why do you think the request method is always 'get'?  It could be that the form is not valid.  Try `else: print(form.errors)` after your `if form.is_valid():` statement, to see if it is.  Also, the form tag should be `<form method='post'>` with the post being lowercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no action mentioned in your form. View function needs to be modified to keep it simple and readable.

[image]